# Easy proof of $\,24^2\mid (pq+1)^2-(p+q)^2$ for $p,q$ coprime to $6$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Any number not divisible by 2 and not divisible by 3 is in the form: $6k\pm1, \quad k \in \mathbb N$

If I have the following:

$$
p = 6a+b, \qquad a \in \mathbb N, \quad b \in \{-1,1\}
$$
$$
q = 6c+d, \qquad c \in \mathbb N, \quad d \in \{-1,1\}
$$
$$
n = p \cdot q
$$
$$
x = \frac{p+q}{2}
$$
$$
y = \frac{q-p}{2}
$$
Then:
$$
\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2-x^2=\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^2-y^2=z \qquad \land \qquad \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^2 = n
$$
Moreover, for any number $n$ in the form $6k\pm1$, $z$ seems to be divisible by 144. I want to prove that $z$ is divisible by 144.

I will try to probe only one case because there are too many cases.

Supose:
$$
\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{p+q}{2}\right)^2 \to \left(\frac{p \cdot q + 1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{p+q}{2}\right)^2
$$
Replacing $p$ and $q$:
$$
\left(\frac{\left(6a+b\right)\left(6c+d\right)+1}{2}\right)^{2}-\left(\frac{\left(6a+b\right)+\left(6c+d\right)}{2}\right)^{2} =
\left(\frac{36ac+6ad+6bc+bd+1}{2}\right)^{2}-\left(\frac{6a+6c+b+d}{2}\right)^{2}
$$
Assuming that $b$ and $d$ are opposite and:
$$
b = 1, \quad d = -1  \to  \left(\frac{36ac-6a+6c}{2}\right)^{2}-\left(\frac{6a+6c}{2}\right)^{2}
$$
Operating and taking common factors:
$$
\left(3\left(6ac+c-a\right)\right)^{2}-\left(3\left(a+c\right)\right)^{2} = 9\left(\left(6ac+c-a\right)^{2}-\left(a+c\right)^{2}\right) =
$$
$$
= 9\left(36a^{2}c^{2}+12\left(c-a\right)ac+\left(c-a\right)^{2}-\left(a+c\right)^{2}\right) =
9\left(36a^{2}c^{2}+12ac^{2}-12a^{2}c-4ac\right) =
$$
$$
9\cdot4\cdot ac\left(9ac+3c-3a-1\right)
$$
If $a$ is even and $c$ is odd:
$$
a = 2i, \quad c = 2j - 1 \to 9\cdot4\cdot\left(2i\right)\left(2j-1\right)\left(9\left(2i\right)\left(2j-1\right)+3\left(2j-1\right)-3\left(2i\right)-1\right) =
$$

Operating and taking common factors:
$$
= 9\cdot4\cdot\left(4ij-2i\right)\left(\left(18i\right)\left(2j-1\right)+\left(6j-3\right)-\left(6i\right)-1\right) =
$$

$$
= 9\cdot4\cdot\left(4ij-2i\right)\left(36ij-18i+6j-6i-4\right) =
$$

$$
= 9\cdot4\cdot2\cdot2\left(2ij-i\right)\left(18ij-9i+3j-3i-2\right) \to 9\cdot4\cdot2\cdot2 = 144
$$

Finally: $z$ is divisible by 144 and $144 = 12^2$

These means solving these equations:
$$
x^2 \equiv \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2 (\textrm{mod}\ 144) \quad \land \quad
y^2 \equiv \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^2 (\textrm{mod}\ 144) 
$$

You can factorize integer number. But for large integer numbers these method don't work.

So:

Taking any assumptions on $a$, $b$, $c$ or $d$ values or any other assumption always gives that $z$ is divisible by 144. I can't develop a demonstration on all cases. With this I didn't prove anything. I can't refute it either.

Is there an easy way to probe this?

And if this is true, is possible to extend it to factor larger numbers?

Comment: $\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^2 = n$ is true for any integer $n$ whether defined as in this question or not.

Comment: By "probe" do you mean "prove"?

Comment: @Théophile Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: No problem; they are related words, ultimately from the same Latin root but whose meanings have diverged a bit in English. To probe is to test something; it is tentative, whereas to prove is quite conclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an easier way, that proves the general case. Using factoring of the difference of squares and [Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick) gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
z & = \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2-x^2 \\
& = \left(\frac{pq+1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{p+q}{2}\right)^2 \\
& = \left(\frac{pq+1}{2}+\frac{p+q}{2}\right)\left(\frac{pq+1}{2}-\frac{p+q}{2}\right) \\
& = \frac{(pq + p + q + 1)(pq - p - q + 1)}{4} \\
& = \frac{(p + 1)(q + 1)(p - 1)(q - 1)}{4}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Proving $144 \mid z$ means showing that

$$144(4) \mid (p - 1)(p + 1)(q - 1)(q + 1) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note $144(4) = 3^2(2^6) = (3(2^3))^2$. Regardless of $b$ being either $-1$ or $1$, one of $p - 1$ and $p + 1$ is $6a$, so we have $3 \mid (p - 1)(p + 1)$. Also, since $p$ is odd, then $p - 1$ and $p + 1$ are consecutive even integers, so one is congruent to $2 \pmod 4$ while the other is congruent to $0 \pmod{4}$, which means their product has a factor of $2(4) = 8$. Thus, $2^3 \mid (p - 1)(p + 1)$. Similarly, $3 \mid (q - 1)(q + 1)$ and $2^3 \mid (q - 1)(q + 1)$. Combined, this proves that \eqref{eq2A} is always true.

Regarding extending this to factoring larger numbers, if I correctly understand what you mean, then that can also generally be done with appropriate values and expressions.

Comment: Good trick! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: **Note** "Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick" is bettter (more conceptually) known as [Completing a Product (or Rectangle)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/651073/242), a straightforward generalization of Completing a Square.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact very easy: applying the well-known  $\rm\color{#c00}{C}$ = [composition law for differences of squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/97903/242)

$$\ \ \ \color{#0a0}{4z} = (pq\!+\!1)^2-(p\!+\!q)^2\overset{\rm\color{#c00}C} = (p^2\!-\!1)(q^2\!-\!1)\ \ \ \ \ \ $$

So $\,\underbrace{24\cdot 6}_{144}\mid z\iff 24^2\mid \color{#0a0}{4z}=(p^2\!-\!1)(q^2\!-\!1),\,$ true by [$\,24\mid n^2\!-\!1\,$ for $n$ coprime to $6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/910/242)  $\ \ \bf\small QED$

---

**Remark** $ $ Just like the e Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity for composition of sums of squares [can be viewed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/916029/242) as arising from the *multiplicativity* of the norms of Gaussian integers, the above composition law fir *differences* of squares can be viewed as arising from norm multiplicativity of [split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) (aka double or perplex numbers), $\,a+b\:\!j\,$ where $\,j^2 = 1.\ \ $